# Autoformat and autoindent source code

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

Some text editors (emacs, vim, etc) have an "autoindent" feature, where you can select the entire code and indent it perfectly (e.g. by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> for emacs, or <kbd>=</kbd> for vim).

Since there is an abundance of badly formatted code in SO, would it be possible to have a feature where you select the entire code and press a button to auto-indent it?  This wouldn't work for whitespace-sensitive languages like Python, but for languages that are more free-form (C, Java, etc), this would be pretty convenient.

Comment: **+1** I cannot count the number of times I've pressed `Ctrl+C` `C-y M-x java-mode RET C-x h TAB C-x h M-w` `Ctrl+V` in the First Posts queue.

Comment: @michaelb958 With a keyboard macro program, you can reduce that to like 2 key presses.

Comment: There has been numerous questions regarding this. I think the main reason it hasn't been implemented is because indentation forms part of coding standards and everyone has their own coding standards. Adding *some* indentation on un-indented or terribly indented code is one thing, but having everyone conform to some specified standards (which is what some people will surely do if it's made so easy) is something else entirely.

Comment: It should be optional, so you can format how you like it, or use the auto-indent feature.  Also, there could be different styles built-in, like k&r, gnu, etc.